# Backbone.js Unable to parse response from collectio.toJSON()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am learning Backbone and it would be great if someone can help me with this issue. After I do a fetch on my collection, in success callback I get the parsed data using `collection.toJSON()`, this actually returns an object and I am unable to get anything out of this object. This object actually has data that I need.

[image: Please see the object contents in this screenshot]

My question is how do I access rows property in my object. Here is my code for your reference

```
  var testCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:myModel,
    url: '/myApiEndPoint',
    data: '',
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.data = models.data;
    },
    fetch: function(options) {
        var ajaxConfig = {
            url: this.url,
            data: this.data,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType: 'text/xml',
            parse: true
        };
        options = _.extend({}, ajaxConfig, options);

        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
    },
    parse: function(xmlResponse) {
            // I have some parsing logic to extract uid and rows from my xmlResponse
            return {
              uid: uid,
              rows: rows
            };
      },
  });

var collObj  = new testCollection({data: xmlQuery1});
collObj.fetch({
  success: function(collection){
    // This code block will be triggered only after receiving the data.
    console.log(collection.toJSON()); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name `toJSON` suggests, it returns you the array of JSON objects where each object is a `Model's` JSON object. You can fetch the required properties in this way:

```
collObj.fetch({
  success: function(collection){
    // This code block will be triggered only after receiving the data.
    console.log(collection.toJSON()); 
    var uid = 'uid-of-an-object-to-access';
    var rows = collection.get(uid).get('rows');
    console.log(rows);
  }
});
```